# How to Remove Parents Category Permalink from Posts

Tags: php, categories, permalinks

Simply speaking i want to do something like this.

```
http://example.com/parent-category/child-category/post-name
```

change into

```
http://example.com/child-category/post-name
```

I found some solutions, but they are not perfect. 
For instance i found this code which do the thing almost right.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_category', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_category( $permalink, $post, $leavename )
{
$cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if ( $cats ) {
    usort( $cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID' );
    $category = $cats[0]->slug;
    if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent ) {
        // Find parent categories and replace them in the link
        $parentcats = get_category_parents( $parent, false, '/', true );
        $permalink = str_replace( $parentcats, '', $permalink );
    }
}
return $permalink;
}
```

Because of str_replace it breaks links if categories has similar names.
Like

```
http://example.com/myhouse/house/post-title
```

It will delete house from both categories. 
Can someone fix this code to work with any names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With either `str_replace` or `preg_replace`, without either some naming conventions on the user end or some strong work in the method's *directives* [(linked, you can read about patterns here,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ), you're going to run into issues with the

`House | My House | New House` scenarios; especially once you're dealing with slugs, and if those slugs are things like `myhouse` and `newhouse`.

Then the questions become "what of grandchildren?", and "what if the post is in multiple child categories with different parents and the wrong parent is in the first position of that `$cats` array?"

---

### Possible Solution: filter the permalink to remove parent categories

The below seemed to work on my end for the scenarios I mentioned above, and it avoids `str_`- and `preg_` -replace altogether.

I assume by your link example:

> http://example.com/myhouse/house/post-title

that your permalinks structure is `/%category%/%postname%/` And that the goal here is to limit the permalink to the youngest member of the category family and post title. So, `example.com/child-cat/post-title/` or `example.com/grandchild-cat/post-title`

Since we know we only want those two last values to remain, and we have the permalink, let's parse it, explode the path portion into an array, count the array entries, keep the last and second-to-last entries, and reform the permalink and return it.

After we make sure we're dealing with a post that even has a child category, of course.

**Something like this maybe:**

```
    add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_category', 10, 3 );
    function remove_parent_category( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

         $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );

         if ( $cats ) {

             foreach ($cats as $cat => $parent) {

               $cat_parent_values[] = $parent->parent; 
             }

             if( array_sum( $cat_parent_values ) > 0 )  {

                 $url_array      = parse_url( $permalink );
                 $url_path       = array_filter( explode( '/', $url_array['path'] ) );
                 $url_path      = array_values($url_path);
                 $url_path_count = count( $url_path );

                 $name_slot      = $url_path_count - 1;  
                 $child_cat_slot = $name_slot - 1;

                 $new_url_path[] = '/'. $url_path[ $child_cat_slot ];
                 $new_url_path[] = '/'. $url_path[ $name_slot ] .'/';

                 $new_permalink  = $url_array['scheme'] .'://'. $url_array['host'] . $new_url_path[0] . $new_url_path[1];

             }//end if sum > 0
         }//end if $cats

        return $new_permalink;
    }
```

A preliminary test of it seems to work on my end on a fresh install, and it with no str_replace it passes the House|MyHouse test. I'm sure it can be improved upon, and you will have to really test it and make sure there aren't any other issues/scenarios that break it. There could very well be a better approach altogether that doesn't involve filtering the permalink, but I'm not sure of one off hand.

### Explanation:

First we use [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) like you already had to get an array of category objects. 
We verify we have some, and then we do a foreach loop of `array as $key => $value`, casting each value to a new array.

Wordpress stores the value of `parent` for a category as the id, and that id is an `(int)`. If there is no parent, it gets a `0`.
So, if the sum of all values in our new array is greater than `0`, we have at least one parent category in there.
And that means we have at least one path part in our permalink we want removed, so we continue.

php's [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will give us an array() of `'scheme' => 'http', 'host' => 'example.com', 'path' => '/category/child-cat/postname/'`

we [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that, `$url_array`, at each `/` which gives us an array of each section. It also gives us some empty array values,
so we wrap it in `array_filter` and it cleans that up for us hopefully and we set it to `$url_path`. The we can use `[array_values()][5]` to clean up any missing numerical keys removed by `array_filter` and give us  `[0],[1],[2]` for keys in an array of three items.

As mentioned earlier, we are assuming the name of the post is at the end, so with our filtered and re-valued array we use `count()` to know how many keys are in this array,
and use that to find our post name by subtracting "one" since the array starts at [0]. Then subtract one from *that* and we have our "youngest category".

Then we put the permalink back together with using our $url_array and the path parts for the post name and category we want to keep, ignoring whatever else was there.

and we return it to the post_link filter.

---

### Other possible issues I noticed with your example:

There are some other potential issues with the example you provided:
`get_the_category()` will return an array of category objects, but if that `usort()` is intended to arrange them by their ids, then if you create a category that becomes the parent to an existing category then first position of that array, `$cats[0]`, will not necessarily be a parent category. (unless I'm misunderstanding the nature of `_usort_terms_by_id`.

It is also unclear what the `$parent` variable in `if($parent = $cats[0]->parent)` is intended to be set to.

Comment: I also found wordpress plugin "No category parents" that works as intended. But from the first look it does not seem as efficient as yours.

Comment: Ok. It does not work as well as i thought. There is a problem with permalinks of every category post that is not subcategory. They all lost their permalinks.

Comment: As I stated, _"I'm sure it can be improved upon, and you will have to really test it and make sure there aren't any other issues/scenarios that break it."_  "Permalinks" have not been "lost." Other than un-accepting the answer, what have you tried in terms of improving upon the code?

Comment: Eh. After testing i simply stated what problem there is with the code you written. And you are actually blaming me for stating the fact? I don't see a point of that. Yes they are lost. If permalinks are not generated it can be also said that they are lost. I fixed it by adding return $permalink;. If there are other problems i will check later when i have time and see for myself.

Comment: Thanks for @hwl's answer and code, the code works great, but it doesn't work with the AMP url, can you fix it with AMP? Look forward to your return.